# How to change log level of Munin's munin-graph.log, munin-html.log, munin-limits.log and munin-update.log?

Tags: linux, logging, centos, rsyslog, munin

I've already changed the log level for "munin-node.log" in "/etc/munin/munin-node.conf" but now that everything is working 100%, how do I change the log level of "munin-graph.log", "munin-html.log", "munin-limits.log" and "munin-update.log"?

They are all located in /var/log/munin/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to change the log level of munin-graph (which is running on log level INFO below version 2.0.7) you can change /usr/share/munin/munin-graph

from:

```
logger_open($config->{'logdir'});
logger_debug() if $config->{debug} or defined($ENV{CGI_DEBUG});
```

to:

```
logger_open($config->{'logdir'});
logger_debug() if $config->{debug} or defined($ENV{CGI_DEBUG});
logger_level("warn");
```

or upgrade to a higher munin version:
see http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/1251

Comment: For "munin-update.log", there is a similar "/usr/share/munin/munin-update" file for which the same solution applies. However, it doesn't work with munin-html.log" and "munin-limits.log".